# How can I download older version of iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone

I've just installed iPhone SDK 4.0 and it appears that the previous version of SDK has vanished from my system.
I was looking for any links to download the previous version of iPhone SDK to download, but I cannot find anything.

Any ideas where I could download it?

Comment: What target are you looking for? SDK 4.0 can target an app for any 3.x OS. In your project build settings set the base SDK to 3.2 and there's an option for 'targeted deployment' and you can set that to anything you like (I have mine set to 3.1.2 at the moment).

Comment: I have Base SDK set to 'iPhone Simulator 3.2" and iPhone OS Deployment Target to 'iPhone OS 3.1.3' and my app is ran in the iPad Simulator.

Any other ideas?

Comment: It's running on the iPad sim because that's how the simulator is setup. v3.2 SDK compiled will run on an iPad (because the ipad is backwards compatible). In the simulator (not xcode) there should be a menu option to change the device to an iPhone. Give that a try (though you should know the sim won't behave any differently).

Comment: Yes, I can change the device to iPhone in the Simulator, but when I go to Settings->General->About I can see Version 4.0 (8A293)

Comment: As does mine. I have a device running 3.1.2 and I can attest that my Build Target is 3.1.2 and works correctly. I use the iPad simulator when I need to but it's more to test functionality than look. Look I always do on a device. Is there a reason you want the sim to run the iPhone vs the iPad? the OS is identical (with a few small exceptions).

Comment: The problem is that my app was running smoothly on 3.1.3 and when I upgraded to 4.0 I can see small differences in its behaviour. I just would like to test it on 3.1.3 again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any new submission or update to appstore must be on IOS 4. The older IPhone sdk's are no more available for download at http://developer.apple.com/. If you think that you still need old version (for example: to run some old example), then try searching for xcode in the torrent sites. You can find there almost any version (at own risk!)